# JQuery AJAX Function Not Working Properly

Tags: php, html, jquery, ajax

I have a table that needs to be updated every time a new entry is made to a database, so I refresh the query (devicesAuto.php) every second.

I have a load function written in JQuery that works fine on its own:

```
<script> 
$('#refresh').load('devicesAuto.php');
</script>
```

But when I pass it into 'setInterval()' it stops working:

```
<script>  
$(document).ready(function(){
    setInterval(function(){
    $('#refresh').load('devicesAuto.php');
    },1000);
});
</script>
```

Comment: Also, it's ok if it is a school or college assignment but do not use setInterval for real time applications. It will load your server a lot. In such cases, between the client and server, server sends and client listens on a port along with usual interaction achieved using sockets.

Comment: Your code isn't reproducible. Please share a minimum verifiable example.  I presume `1000` is too less of a timeline for a HTTP request to get served completely. Increase it to say `5000` and try again

Comment: are there any errors in console?